# Solution to Schrödinger equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, schroedinger-equation

I'm trying to solve the Schrödinger equation for a given potential. With some assumptions I end up with:

$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2M}\frac{d^2u(r)}{dr^2} = - \left(E - V(r)\right)u(r)$$

Since it's a square well potential I'm looking at, I have for the first region ($r \leq r_0$) that $V(r) = V_0$. So if I plug that into the above equation and solve that differential equation, I end up with:

$$u(r) = A\sin(kr) + B\cos(kr),$$
where $k = \sqrt{2M(E+V_0)}/\hbar$. I can then make some conditions and stuff to reduce it even further, but that's not my problem.

The next region ($r > r_0$) I get that $V(r) = 0$, which mean I have to solve:
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2M}\frac{d^2u(r)}{dr^2} = - E\,u(r)$$

In my books, and websites I've seen, the solution to this is the same as above (With different constants) and the expontential functions instead of cosine and sine. And this is what I don't understand, why is that ? Whenever I try to solve that on my computer, I still get cosine and sine, but no exponential functions - which I think makes sense, since the only difference is some constant for the potential.

So what am I missing ? Am I solving it the wrong way, or is there some trick I don't know ?

Comment: Just take [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) into account, and you should see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is that you're interested in $E < 0$. Such states are "bound" in the square well. The equation:

$ \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} ~=~ - k^2 ~ f(x)$

is solved by $f(x) ~=~ A e^{i k x} + B e^{-i k x}$. If $k^2 < 0$ then you get another $i$ in this picture and you switch from sinusoidal behavior to plus/minus exponential behavior.

Comment: Not necessarily. He could be interested in reflection coefficients above the square well. He didn't specify. The principles of $E>V(r)$ or $E<V(r)$ still hold.

Comment: That's true; I was just assuming that because he was *looking for exponentials* that he wanted the bound states.

Answer (score 1):

First, the $k$ in the first region is incorrect. Check your signs. You should have
$$k_{I} = \sqrt{2M(E-V_o)}/\hbar.$$

Second, your solution to the second region will have sine and cosine solutions with 
$$ k_{II} = \sqrt{2ME}/\hbar.$$

Real exponential solutions will occur in each region if $E<V_o$ in region one and/or $E<0$ in region II.

Look at the DE; if it has the form
$$ f'' = -af$$
where $f$ is a differentiable function and a is a positive constant, the solution is sines and cosines.

If the form is $$f''=a f $$, the solution will be exponentials.

Comment: My mistake, it's $V(r) = -V_0$, not positive $V_0$. So in that case, won't I end up with a negative result inside the square root in region one ? If $E$ is negative and $V_0$is negative...

Comment: You're getting confused by all the negative signs.  Is $V_o$ a positive number with $V(r) = -V_o$ being a negative potential?  If $E>V(r)$ (not absolute values, but actual properly signed values) you will have sinusoidal behavior. If $E<V(r)$  you will have exponential behavior.

Comment: Ah yes, that's purely on me. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Now, do you have 3 regions, each with different potentials or only 2 regions? You say you have a square well. The means 3 regions, and the one in the middle has a potential *lower* than the outside regions.  Next, is the energy E lower or higher than the outside potentials (if it's a well)?